# Solving an exponential equation

Tags: logarithms

Alright, here's the equation:

$$‎1.08^x = 1.10^{x-1}$$

I know I need to use logarithms, but I can't figure how to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Begin by taking the log of both sides.  Then look at the [property of logs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities) to see if you can reduce either of the sides to something nicer!

Comment: Your right-hand side is ambiguous.  Is the exponent $x-1$, or is the exponent $x$?  I.e., is the equation $1.08^x=1.10^{x-1}$ or $1.08^x=1.10^x-1$?

Comment: The left one, sorry Jonas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an extremely specific instance of properties of the logarithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't get hung up on the fact that the bases don't match. The so-called power rule (or exponent rule) for logarithms works for any base.

$$
\begin{align*}
1.08^x &= 1.10^{x-1}\\
\ln\left(1.08^x\right) &= \ln\left(1.10^{x-1}\right)\\
x\ln(1.08) &= (x-1)\ln(1.10)\\
x\ln(1.08) &= x\ln(1.10) - \ln(1.10)\\
x\ln(1.08) - x\ln(1.10) &= - \ln(1.10)\\
x(\ln(1.08) - \ln(1.10)) &= - \ln(1.10)\\
x &= \frac{-\ln(1.10)}{\ln(1.08) - \ln(1.10)}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I happen to have some more worked examples from a Pre-Calculus course I taught a couple years ago. I hope they are helpful to you. http://austinmohr.com/Home_files/log%20worksheet.pdf